# Load bearing columns and railing

Tags: porch, railing, load

I have a porch railing in which I am certain the columns are load bearing, however, my wife wants me to remove the railing portion.  My question is, is this safe to do?  Does the railing serve any structural support for the columns?  If I were to remove the railing (leaving the columns) will I compromise the structure?  It is 3 columns equally spaced with 6 ft sections of railing between them totaling approximately 12 feet of railing.

Comment: A photo of your structure would help you get a complete answer here. Note that railings are required in many situations (decks higher than 30" off the ground, for example) but posts and columns are required to be self-supporting since they support other structures.

Comment: Without at least a pic showing the posts supporting the deck and the railings above the deck (and any roof if there is one), all we can do is speculate. Your use of English leads me to believe you're in or from the US, but a location would also be most helpful, as code varies from country to country and even state to state.

Comment: Chances are, if you take the railing off nothing will fall down, but you'll have to put them back on if you want to sell the house. Like they said before me, it ultimately depends on where you're located.